# How to pass changeDetectorRef to decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular2-changedetection, angular-decorator

I'm creating my own decorator for the property that will automatically synchronize value of the property with firebase db. My decorator is preety simple and looks like this:

```js
export function AutoSync(firebasePath: string) {
    return (target: any, propertyKey: string) => {
        let   _propertyValue = target[propertyKey];

        // get reference to db
        const _ref           = firebase.database().ref(firebasePath);

        // listen for data from db
        _ref.on('value', snapshot => {
            _propertyValue = snapshot.val();
        });

        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
            get: () => _propertyValue,
            set: (v) => {
                _propertyValue = v;
                _ref.set(v);
            },
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```js
@AutoSync('/config') configuration;
```

And it (almost) works like a charm. My `configuration` property is automatically synchronised with firebase db object on the path `/config`. Property setter automatically updates the value in db - that works great!

Now the problem: when value in database is being updated in firebase db by some other app than we get the snapshow and value of `_propertyValue` is being correcly updated but changeDetection is not triggered as the `configuration` property is not changed directly.

So I need to do that manually. I was thinking of triggering change detector from the function in decorator but I'm not sure how to pass an instance of change detector to the decorator.

I have come with a walkaround: In `app.component`'s constructor I save reference to change detector instance in global window object:

```js
constructor(cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    window['cd'] = cd;

    (...)
}
```

Now I can use it in my `AutoSync` decorator like this:

```js
// listen for data from db
_ref.on('value', snapshot => {
    _propertyValue = snapshot.val();
    window['cd'].detectChanges();
});
```

but this is kind of hacky and dirty solution. What is the right way?

Comment: This is primarily TypeScript question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to pass class property value to a decorator. Saving provider reference to a global variable is not just hacky but wrong solution, because there may be more than one class instance, and thus more than one provider instance.

Property decorator is evaluated once on class definition, where `target` is class `prototype`, and it is expected that `propertyKey` property is defined there. `_ref` and `_propertyValue` are same for all instances, `_ref.on` is called and listened even if the component was never instantiated.

An workaround is to expose desired provider instance on class instance - or `injector` if several providers should be accessed in a decorator. Since each component instance should set up its own `_ref.on` listener, it should be performed in class constructor or `ngOnInit` hook. It's impossible to patch constructor from property decorator, but `ngOnInit` should be patched:

```
export interface IChangeDetector {
  cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef;
}

export function AutoSync(firebasePath: string) {
  return (target: IChangeDetector, propertyKey: string) => {
    // same for all class instances
    const initialValue = target[propertyKey];

    const _cbKey = '_autosync_' + propertyKey + '_callback';
    const _refKey = '_autosync_' + propertyKey + '_ref';
    const _flagInitKey = '_autosync_' + propertyKey + '_flagInit';
    const _flagDestroyKey = '_autosync_' + propertyKey + '_flagDestroy';
    const _propKey = '_autosync_' + propertyKey;

    let ngOnInitOriginal = target['ngOnInit'];
    let ngOnDestroyOriginal = target['ngOnDestroy']

    target['ngOnInit'] = function () {
      if (!this[_flagInitKey]) {
        // wasn't patched for this key yet
        this[_flagInitKey] = true;

        this[_cbKey] = (snapshot) => {
          this[_propKey] = snapshot.val();
        };

        this[_refKey] = firebase.database().ref(firebasePath);
        this[_refKey].on('value', this[_cbKey]);
      }

      if (ngOnInitOriginal)
        return ngOnInitOriginal.call(this);
    };

    target['ngOnDestroy'] = function () {
      if (!this[_flagDestroyKey]) {
        this[_flagDestroyKey] = true;
        this[_refKey].off('value', this[_cbKey]);
      }

      if (ngOnDestroyOriginal)
        return ngOnDestroyOriginal.call(this);
    };

    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
      get() {
        return (_propKey in this) ? this[_propKey] : initialValue;
      },
      set(v) {
        this[_propKey] = v;
        this[_refKey].set(v);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      },
    });

  }
}

class FooComponent implements IChangeDetector {
  @AutoSync('/config') configuration;

  constructor(public cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
}
```

It is considered a hack

Comment: I see. There is no good way to do this due to described limitations. I updated the answer, but setting other properties rather than the one that prop decorator belongs to is considered a hack.

Comment: Your first anser was better in my opinion and with a few modifications it works great! Thanks!

Comment: A more complex but correct solution would be to move everything but Object.defineProperty to parent class and inherit from it. So the component is `class Foo extends Autosyncable`. And only Autosyncable classes can have @Autosync decorators.

Comment: I went again through your solution! works great! Few mistakes I have notices: 1. in `ngOnInit` you should check `if (!this[_refKey])`, 2. In `ngOnDestroy` you should check `if (this[_refKey])`, 3. In `target[_cbKey]` function you should assign value to `target[_propKey]`. Besides it works great! One more thing: how can I get reference to redefined object (I would like to use proxy here)?

Comment: Glad it works, I didn't have chance to test it. Regarding 1 & 2, I believe it should be `!this[_cbKey]`, it tests if *class prototype* was already patched (`!this[_refKey]` is always true). Skipping it will make it patched multiple times, which is a no-no. `target[_propKey]` isn't suitable because ref subscription deals will class instance, and is a prototype. I guess that both `target[_propKey]` and `this[_propKey]` will work here, but the latter makes more sense, and the former may cause performance and memory issues.

Comment: 1. `this[_cbKey]` always extists as this is the function defined earlier (`target[_cbKey]`) so it never enters the if statement (tested). 3. `this` is `null` in `target[_cbKey]` function.

Comment: Yes, this happened during refactoring. I've updated the code, it should be ok now. Additional flag prop is necessary here then, as it's usual in situations like this one.

Comment: Thanks @estus! You saved my day! :)